# WordPress comment form autocomplete off

Tags: wordpress

I need to disable autocomplete function for comment forms defined in comment-template.php file

```
2478         '<form autocomplete="off" action="%s" method="post" id="%s" class="%s"%s>'
```

This is my working version - but I need to be able to keep this working after update.
What is the clean way to patch WordPress core files when there is no do_action or other method for doing so.

Comment: What you can do is create child theme from the main theme & extend comment-template.php file there so whatever update you make to that file won't change after the update.

Comment: In this case this file is located in WordPress core. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1564/modifying-wordpress-core-files - this nearly answeres my question.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a child template, then override specific file into specific path.

after all you can be sure updating your template does not effect your modification

so you create a comment-template.php in your child template

for creating child template please visit following link
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/